# Http Request Flutter didn't have body

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I have a project with Flutter. And I want to get data from API. In my other project, I don't have any problem. But in this project, I have a problem. When I debug the process, in HTTP response didn't have body from API.

In class AuthService to get the API.

```
Future<ResponseCheckNIP> checkNIP({String? nip}) async {
 var url = '$baseUrl/check-nip-new/$nip';
 var header = {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
 };
 // var body = jsonEncode({'nip': nip});
 var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: header);
 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
   ResponseCheckNIP responseCheckNIP = ResponseCheckNIP.fromJson(data);
   return responseCheckNIP;
 } else {
   throw Exception('Get NIP Failed');
 }
}
```

And when I debug it, I get this

[image]

as we see, there is no body in there. Am I did something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely, the data is actually in the `response.bodyBytes`.

And Since you cannot directly convert `bytes` to `json` with `dart`, convert `bytes` to `String` first then decode the `String` using `jsonDecode`.

Below is the modified code.

```
Future<ResponseCheckNIP> checkNIP({String? nip}) async {
  var url = '$baseUrl/check-nip-new/$nip';
  var header = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  };
  var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: header);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    
    // Get body bytes from response
    final bytes = response.bodyBytes;
    // Convert bytes to String then decode
    final data = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(bytes));

    ResponseCheckNIP responseCheckNIP = ResponseCheckNIP.fromJson(data);
    return responseCheckNIP;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Get NIP Failed');
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.
Thank you.